# What is the best node.js server architecture for handling thousands of api calls?

Tags: node.js, database-design, architecture

I am trying to understand the server architecture that can handle continuous requests from many devices that send their location and other relative data.
I was thinking that I need real-time DB like rethingDB or firebase, but I don't quite understand the flow of the process because I am a newbie.

What is the best approach at handling thousands of requests and analyzing them and then showing the result in real-time on the front-end?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that your main Node JS event loop is not blocked by slow synchronous calls.

Use 'cluster' module and 'worker-threads' module to offload computation and distribute request handling.

These two will ensure that you are using all available resources (cores, memory and i/o) and your main Node JS event loop is always handling the max possible client requests.